# Allowing other people to ssh port-forward to my Linux VPS

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

I have an Ubuntu VPS which I sometimes use as a `SOCKS` proxy to browse the internet. I use the ssh dynamic port-forwarding command as follows:

```
ssh -fNTC -D 1080 username@vpsIP
```

then set my browser's proxy to `localhost:1080` as a `SOCKS`.

I have created an additional user with the username '*dudes*' on the VPS for a few friends to be able to ssh port forward too and get something akin a VPN (we don't need the network part of VPN).

Now I really do not want to run my VPS as a VPN server, so I'd like to stick to ssh port forwarding or similar.

**How do I prevent the *dudes* user from being able to open a secure shell and start messing things up on the VPS?**

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the shell of the user 'dudes'?

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin dudes
```

or if your OS doesn't have nologin :

```
usermod -s /bin/false dudes
```

Comment: I have just tried this. When trying to 'ssh dudes@vpsIP' the VPS attempts to login dudes in but then stops the procedure and return to my computer's shell, thus preventing dudes from logging in. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities. But the easiest will be probably option `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config`. It will not allow running any command and if they will want to run some, it will run this one.

Example snippet of `sshd_config`:

```
Match User dudes  #your dudes user -- you can also match group
  ForceCommand /bin/true
```

Comment: Have just tried. It works so thank you. very elegant, as it kills the login/shell creation attempt dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use key based authentication (which I strongly recommend that you do), then you can limit what each key is allowed to do through the `authorized_keys` file.

Specifying `command="/bin/false"` in front of the key would prevent them from invoking a shell or any command other than the one you put in `authorized_keys`.

There are other restrictions you can impose through `authorized_keys`. For a full list see the `sshd` man page.